# How to display Japanese Characters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, character, textfield, cjk

I try to develop an ios app, I want to make something about Japanese characters.
My app will display latin alphabet to the user.But this user each tap any latin characters, I will set text Japanese characters in textfield. How to do this ? Thanks a lot from now.

Answer (score 1):

You want the UITextFieldDelegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

It fires, every time, the user adds or deletes a letter or many letters. To use it, you have to set the delegate of the TextField to your ViewController.

For example you could write (assuming that you have a function called `asJapanese`, which converts the latin letters to japanese):

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.count > 0 {
            if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
               let japaneseString = asJapanese(string)
               let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: japaneseString)

               textField.text = updatedText
               return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot actually I used this already but I can not find like a library that provides converting latin alphaet to japanese, Hirgana/katakana :)

Comment: Oh okay, I can't help you with this ;)

Comment: https://github.com/rasserudenisu/JPString  I found this Japanese Convert Class I solved it!!  Thans a lot Josef I will use your delegate method :)